# How to get list of questions by status?

Tags: support, search

How to get a list of the questions according to status as:

1. No answers.
2. On hold, requiring improvement.
3. With no up-voted answers (which number is advertised in the site but I can find how to access them) By the way, it would be pretty comfortable if the text advertising the lots of questions without upvoted answers were also a link to that list of questions.

Comment: Searching for [is:q+answers:0](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=is:q+answers:0) should give you the questions with no answers. If you have a look [in help](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching) you will see that there is also *closed:* operator. However, I do not think you can distinguish close reasons using search.

Comment: In your third point, do you mean [this list](http://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered/) of [unanswered questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/unanswered-questions/info)?

Comment: Google can help with closed questions, search: `site:math.stackexchange.com "put on hold as" "missing context"`

Comment: Re: *By the way, it would be pretty comfortable if the text advertising the lots of questions without upvoted answers were also a link to that list of questions.* You can post it as a feature request, if you think that it would be useful. But I have to admit that I do not even know where is this *"text advertising the lots of questions without upvoted answers"*.